# Putting a vertical line next to an exercise

Tags: framed

I'm working with an existing environment (exercise) provided by the svmono documentstyle (springer monographs) and sometimes it is unclear where an exercise ends and the next paragraph begins.

To solve this, I am trying to add a vertical line to the left of the text.  I am using the `framed` package for this, using a modification of `leftbar`.  I'm not quite sure where I got this from, but a problem I have is that the bar extends about a line too high and to low on either side of the exercise.  Thus the exercise now takes up too much vertical space.  Here is an example using amsthm for the environment rather than the provided version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{%
    \def\FrameCommand
    {%
        {\hspace{-0.5ex}\vrule width 0.5pt}%
        \hspace{0ex}%must no space.
        \fboxsep=\FrameSep%
    }%
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\let\oldexercise\exercise
\let\oldendexercise\endexercise
\def\exercise{\begingroup \begin{leftbar}\oldexercise}
\def\endexercise{\oldendexercise \end{leftbar}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
some text
\begin{exercise}
here is exercise 1. 
\end{exercise}
more text
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to modify this so that the bar does not cause the environment to take up extra vertical space?  (alternately - since this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - is there a better alternative to make the exercise clearly distinct from the rest of the text?)

Comment: Could you post a fully compilable, yet minimal, code, that we can play with?

Comment: @bernard - A bit hard because it relies on an existing environment, but I'll build one.  Give me a few minutes

Comment: OK. B.t.w., if the `exercise` environment is based on `amsthm`, you might use a customised version of `\qedhere` or/and a `\small` font size.

Comment: @Bernard Got the example in.  It uses amsthm for the sample.  I don't want to play with font sizes/shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a solution based on `mdframed`, which is easy to customise. Hope it's close to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=0.5pt, topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false,%
leftmargin=0pt, innerleftmargin=0.4em, rightmargin=0pt, innerrightmargin=0pt, innertopmargin=-5pt ,%
innerbottommargin=3pt, splittopskip=\topskip, splitbottomskip=0.3\topskip, %
skipabove=0.6\topsep]%
{exercise}{Exercise}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{exercise}
Here is exercise 1. You must answer the following question:  why is it that
    \[ 1 + 1 = 2  \]%
\end{exercise}
more text

\end{document}
```

[image]